# Get Multiple Values from repeated nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to fetch values from nested JSON , and this fetching is required for all the data points (Count >1000)

following is the JSON array i want to search on , like i'm getting `key` at level 6 from another system and based on the `key` i want to extract its value and value of its adjacent parent 
like key  be `1233` its value will be `blah 6` its parent's value will be `blah 5` and `blah 4`

```
{
    "collection": [{
        "id": "1:ABC",
        "key": "123",
        "value": "blah 1",
        "children": [{
            "id": "2:ABC",
            "key": "456",
            "value": "blah 2",
            "children": [{
                "id": "3:ABC",
                "key": "987",
                "value": "blah 3",
                "children": [{
                    "id": "4:ABC",
                    "key": "3445",
                    "value": "blah 4",
                    "children": [{
                        "id": "5:ABC",
                        "key": "7665",
                        "value": "blah 5",
                        "children": [{
                            "id": "6:ABC",
                            "key": "1233",
                            "value": "blah 6",
                            "children": [{
                                "id": "7:ABC",
                                "key": "7655",
                                "value": "blah1 7",
                                "children": []
                            }, {
                                "id": "7:DEF",
                                "key": "7655",
                                "value": "blah2 7",
                                "children": []
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

**Updated** :

Approach i have implemented:

```
flattenJSON(actualJSONArrayObj){
    const flattenedObj: any = {};

    for (const level1 of actualJSONArrayObj) {
        for (const level2 of level1.children) {
            for (const level3 of level2.children) {
                for (const level4 of level3.children) {
                    for (const level5 of level4.children) {
                        for (const level6 of level5.children) {
                                flattenedObj[level6.key] = {
                                   level4:level4.value
                                   level5:level5.value,
                                   level6:level6.value,
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return flattenedObj;
  }

var flattenedObj = flattenJSON(collection);
console.log(flattenedObj['1233'].level4); //output blah 4
```

Comment: One way is to write a recursive code, where to pass each array to the code and when you find what you're looking for start returning.

Comment: What is your expected output>

Comment: like getFromJSON('blah 6') should return like ```{'level6Value':'blah 6','level5Value':'blah 5','level4Value':'blah 4'}```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Depth First Search Algorithm` to find desired elements in hierarchical data:

```
const sourceData = {
    "id": "1:ABC",
    "key": "123",
    "value": "blah 1",
    "children": [{
        "id": "2:ABC",
        "key": "456",
        "value": "blah 2",
        "children": [{
            "id": "3:ABC",
            "key": "987",
            "value": "blah 3",
            "children": [{
                "id": "4:ABC",
                "key": "3445",
                "value": "blah 4",
                "children": [{
                    "id": "5:ABC",
                    "key": "7665",
                    "value": "blah 5",
                    "children": [{
                        "id": "6:ABC",
                        "key": "1233",
                        "value": "blah 6",
                        "children": [{
                            "id": "7:ABC",
                            "key": "7655",
                            "value": "blah1 7",
                            "children": []
                        }, {
                            "id": "7:DEF",
                            "key": "7655",
                            "value": "blah2 7",
                            "children": []
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
};
```

and code is:

```
function test(targetId) {
    const desiredItems = getNodeByKey(sourceData, 'blah 5', 'value');
    console.log(desiredItems);

}


// Depth First Search Algorithm
function getNodeByKey(obj, targetId, paramKey) {
    if (obj[paramKey] == targetId) {
        return obj;
    }
    if (obj.children) {
        for (let item of obj.children) {
            let check = this.getNodeByKey(item, targetId, paramKey)
            if (check) {
                return check;
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}

console.log(test('blah 5'));
```

**UPDATE:**

Usually when we have a hierarchical data, then we have a `parent key` in our data:

```
const sourceData = {
    "id": "1:ABC",
    "key": "123",
    "parentKey": null,
    "value": "blah 1",
    "children": [{
        "id": "2:ABC",
        "key": "456",
        "parentKey": "123",
        "value": "blah 2",
        "children": [{
            "id": "3:ABC",
            "key": "987",
            "value": "blah 3",
            "parentKey": "456",
            "children": [{
                "id": "4:ABC",
                "key": "3445",
                "value": "blah 4",
                "parentKey": "987",
                "children": [{
                    "id": "5:ABC",
                    "key": "7665",
                    "parentKey": "3445",
                    "value": "blah 5",
                    "children": [{
                        "id": "6:ABC",
                        "key": "1233",
                        "parentKey": "7665",
                        "value": "blah 6",
                        "children": [{
                            "id": "7:ABC",
                            "key": "7655",
                            "parentKey": "1233",
                            "value": "blah1 7",
                            "children": []
                        }, {
                            "id": "7:DEF",
                            "key": "7655",
                            "parentKey": "1233",
                            "value": "blah2 7",
                            "children": []
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
};
```

and then you are available get parent object:

```
function test(targetId) {
    const desiredItems = getNodeByKey(sourceData, 'blah 5', 'value');
    let parent;
    if (desiredItems && desiredItems.parentKey) {
        parent = getNodeByKey(sourceData, desiredItems.parentKey, 'key');
    }

    console.log(desiredItems);
    console.log('parent', parent);

}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

If you want to get parent node, then you can use this adjusted function to get parent node by children key:

```
// Depth First Search Algorithm - get parent node
function getParentNodeByChildrenKey(obj, targetId, paramKey) {    
    if (obj.children) {
        if (obj.children.some(ch => ch.value === targetId))
            return obj;
        else {
            for (let item of obj.children) {
                let check = this.getParentNodeByChildrenKey(item, targetId, paramKey)
                if (check) {
                    return check;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null
 }
```

and then you are available get parent object by its children key:

```
function test() {
    const parentObjectByChildrenKey = getParentNodeByKey(sourceData, 'blah 5', 'value');
    console.log(`parentObjectByChildrenKey is `, parentObjectByChildrenKey);
}

console.log(test());
```

Comment: i tried this approach already but was not able to get it's parent values like 
```{'level6Value':'blah 6','level5Value':'blah 5','level4Value':'blah 4'}```

Comment: is any other approach where i can transpose this json into flat table and get the value from it

Comment: currently i don't have any mapper to the parent nodes , i have updated my question with something basic that i have currently implemented

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use this https://lodash.com/docs#filter, because there is no common solution for your task.